# Terraform: can module's name be resolved dynmically?

Tags: terraform

Given a series of modules whose names follow a pattern:

```
module "mod-a" {
  // ...
}

module "mod-b" {
  // ...
}

module "mod-b" {
  // ...
}
```

and assuming each module defines an output called `my_output`, can I refer to a particular module on the basis of a dynamically resolved name?

e.g.

```
...
// some_module = "mod-a"
some_value = module[some_module].my_output
...
```

The syntax above gives the error:

```
The "module" object cannot be accessed directly. Instead, access one of its
attributes.
```

Is there another way to access a module whose name is only known at runtime?

Comment: Nope. You can't dynamically access resource addresses in anyway, whether that's the resource name, the resource type or the module name(s). If instead you try and explain what you're trying to achieve with a real world example then we can maybe provide an alternative option that would work for you.

Answer (score 6):

To achieve this in Terraform today (Terraform 0.12.13), you'll need to construct a suitable map explicitly as a local value, and then index that map:

```
locals {
  modules = {
    mod_a = module.mod_a
    mod_b = module.mod_b
    mod_c = module.mod_c
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in the configuration you can then use an expression like `local.modules[local.dynamic_module_key]`, selecting the desired object from the map.

Terraform requires static references to objects like this so that it can properly construct a dependency graph. In this case, Terraform infers that `local.modules` depends on all of the outputs from all three of these modules, and thus anything that refers to `local.modules` must wait until all of the outputs from all of these modules are ready to ensure that the final index operation has a complete value to work with.

Comment: The person who posted the question never accepted your answer. Thanks to your answer, it helped me out with an issue I got stuck with.